# Why does my contact form work in Brave but not other browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

[image: 1]

My form works in Brave on my computer but does not work on Safari or Google on my computer. It also does not work on mobile devices. Where it does not work it returns a POST 409 Error.

Here is my html code.

```
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="result"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="userName" class="d-none"></label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name:" required id="userName" name="userName">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="companyName" class="d-none"></label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Company Name"  id="companyName" name="companyName">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="d-none"></label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email:" required id="email" name="email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="button gradient-btn w-100" id="submit_btn">subscribe</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

if($_POST)
{

    require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();


    $your_email = "contact@thordigi.com";  //Replace with recipient email address

    $to_Email       = $your_email;

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone =  $_POST["userPhone"];
    //$user_Subject =  $_POST["userSubject"];
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }


       //Server settings
//    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
//    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.googlemail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
//    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
//    $mail->Username   = 'website@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
//    $mail->Password   = 'your password';                         // SMTP password
//    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
//    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
     $mail->setFrom($user_Email,$user_Name);
     $mail->addAddress($your_email, 'Theme Industry');     // Add a recipient
     $mail->addReplyTo($your_email, 'Information');


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'New Contact Inquiry from your Website';
    $mail->Body  = "<h4 style='text-align: center;padding: 25px 15px;background-color: #0c6c9e;color: #FFFFFF;font-size:16px;width:90%;border-radius: 10px;'>Hi There! You have a new inquiry from your website.</h4><br><br>";


    $mail->Body .= "<strong>Name: </strong>". $user_Name ."<br>";
    $mail->Body .= "<strong>Email: </strong>". $user_Email ."<br>";
    $mail->Body .= "<strong>Phone: </strong>". $user_Phone ."<br>";
    $mail->Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $user_Message ."<br>";

    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send())
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .' Thank you for contacting us.'));
        die($output);
    }

}
?>
```

Here is my Javascript code

```
   //contact us

    $("#submit_btn1 , #submit_btn").on('click', function () {

        let userName = $('#name1').val();

        let userEmail = $('#email1').val();

        let userMessage = $('#message1').val();

        let result;

        if(this.id === 'submit_btn'){

            result = $('#result');

            userMessage = $('#companyName').val();

            userName = $('#userName').val();

            userEmail = $('#email').val();

        }

        else{

            result = $('#result1');

        }

        //simple validation at client's end

        let postData, output;

        let proceed = true;

        if (userName === "") {

            proceed = false;

        }

        if (userEmail === "") {

            proceed = false;

        }

        if (userMessage === "") {

            proceed = false;

        }

        //everything looks good! proceed...

        if (proceed) {



            //data to be sent to server

            postData = {

                'userName': userName,

                'userEmail': userEmail,

                'userMessage': userMessage

            };



            //Ajax post data to server

            $.post('https://thordigi.com/contact.php', postData, function (response) {

                //load json data from server and output message

                if (response.type === 'error') {

                    output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">' + response.text + '</div>';

                } else {

                    output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">' + response.text + '</div>';

                    //reset values in all input fields

                    $('.getin_form input').val('');

                    $('.getin_form textarea').val('');



                }



                result.slideUp("fast").html(output).slideDown();

            }, 'json');



        } else {

            output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">Please provide the missing fields.</div>';

            result.slideUp("fast").html(output).slideDown();

        }



    });
```

I have been stuck on this for awhile so I really appreciate the help!

Comment: 409 is a weird one, that status code has something to do with "conflicting resources." Not sure what exactly could be conflicting here - perhaps it is due to the _normal_ form submission you are still letting happen here, "in parallel" to your AJAX request ...?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? Does your server's error log contain more details?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried to change my references and move files around. There is nothing in the error log. I did attach a photo of the error to the original question. I am newer to web development so please forgive any lack of knowledge I have. I believe that the error is with javascript because nothing appears to run when I get the error. If there is anything else I can get to help clarify just ask. Thanks!

Comment: @Cbroe -  Should I try disable this normal form submission and see if it runs?

Answer (score 1):

There are often broswer differences, and some are more forgiving than others. Errors like this are generally down to something not rendering correctly (so that your code can't find the right fields etc). To check the HTML, run it through the [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and see what it suggests.

If that doesn't help, then to see exactly what is being sent and received by each browser, I'd recommend using a man-in-the-middle proxy (like [burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy/using)) to intercept the request and response. From looking at the raw data, it is often quickly apparent what the problem is.